# Preprocessing image for Tensorflow model instead Pytorch preprocessing

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, python-imaging-library

I had a pytorch resnet101 encoder model, when input image got this preprocessing:

```
import torchvision as tv
from PIL import Image

data_transforms = tv.transforms.Compose([
    tv.transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
    tv.transforms.ToTensor(),
    tv.transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])
img = Image.open(img_path)
img = img.convert('RGB')
img = data_transforms(img)
img = torch.FloatTensor(img)
img = img.unsqueeze(0)
print(img)
```

[pytorch image tensor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1gzu.jpg)

Shape of input for encoder in this case is [1, 3, 224, 224], and this picture is normalized with the mean and std of ImageNet.
**Now I'm export this model to tensorflow, so, how to make the same image preprocessing for tf-model?**

I tried to do something like this:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open(img_path)
img = img.convert('RGB')
img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
img = tf.image.resize(tf_img, (224, 224))
img = tf.keras.applications.resnet.preprocess_input(img)# now shape is [224, 224, 3]
img = tf.reshape(img, [1, 3, 224, 224])
print(img)
```

[tensorflow image tensor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQh79.jpg)

but I'm sure that I did something wrong, becouse torch and tf tensors looks very different for one image and give completely different output results from one encoder model.

Can anyone helps, what should I fix in tf preprocessing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
img = Image.open(img_path)
img = img.convert('RGB')
```

could be replaced with

```
image = tf.io.read_file(filename=filepath)
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3) #or decode_png
```

Also, the opposite of `unsqueeze` and `squeeze` is `expand_dims`:

```
  img = tf.expand_dims(img,axis=0)
```

Everything should work well, just ensure that

```
tf.keras.applications.resnet.preprocess_input(img) `and` data.transforms()
```

yield the desired/necessary transformations.

As for the photos, I am quite sure that you missed a /255.0 in case of PyTorch or added a 255.0 division in case of TensorFlow.

In fact, when digging deep into the Keras backend, you can see that when you call your preprocessing function, it will call this function here:

```
def _preprocess_numpy_input(x, data_format, mode):
  """Preprocesses a Numpy array encoding a batch of images.

  Arguments:
    x: Input array, 3D or 4D.
    data_format: Data format of the image array.
    mode: One of "caffe", "tf" or "torch".
      - caffe: will convert the images from RGB to BGR,
          then will zero-center each color channel with
          respect to the ImageNet dataset,
          without scaling.
      - tf: will scale pixels between -1 and 1,
          sample-wise.
      - torch: will scale pixels between 0 and 1 and then
          will normalize each channel with respect to the
          ImageNet dataset.

  Returns:
      Preprocessed Numpy array.
  """
  if not issubclass(x.dtype.type, np.floating):
    x = x.astype(backend.floatx(), copy=False)

  if mode == 'tf':
    x /= 127.5
    x -= 1.
    return x
  elif mode == 'torch':
    x /= 255.
    mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
    std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
  else:
    if data_format == 'channels_first':
      # 'RGB'->'BGR'
      if x.ndim == 3:
        x = x[::-1, ...]
      else:
        x = x[:, ::-1, ...]
    else:
      # 'RGB'->'BGR'
      x = x[..., ::-1]
    mean = [103.939, 116.779, 123.68]
    std = None

  # Zero-center by mean pixel
  if data_format == 'channels_first':
    if x.ndim == 3:
      x[0, :, :] -= mean[0]
      x[1, :, :] -= mean[1]
      x[2, :, :] -= mean[2]
      if std is not None:
        x[0, :, :] /= std[0]
        x[1, :, :] /= std[1]
        x[2, :, :] /= std[2]
    else:
      x[:, 0, :, :] -= mean[0]
      x[:, 1, :, :] -= mean[1]
      x[:, 2, :, :] -= mean[2]
      if std is not None:
        x[:, 0, :, :] /= std[0]
        x[:, 1, :, :] /= std[1]
        x[:, 2, :, :] /= std[2]
  else:
    x[..., 0] -= mean[0]
    x[..., 1] -= mean[1]
    x[..., 2] -= mean[2]
    if std is not None:
      x[..., 0] /= std[0]
      x[..., 1] /= std[1]
      x[..., 2] /= std[2]
  return x
```

The default `mode` parameter in Keras and TensorFlow for preprocessing for ResNet50, is surprisingly not `tf` but `caffe`.

Therefore, the preprocessing that is done to the image is on this else branch( I am adding the else branch and the code thereafter so that you can follow the transformations and see what you are missing):

```
 else:
    if data_format == 'channels_first':
      # 'RGB'->'BGR'
      if x.ndim == 3:
        x = x[::-1, ...]
      else:
        x = x[:, ::-1, ...]
    else:
      # 'RGB'->'BGR'
      x = x[..., ::-1]
    mean = [103.939, 116.779, 123.68]
    std = None
# Zero-center by mean pixel
  if data_format == 'channels_first':
    if x.ndim == 3:
      x[0, :, :] -= mean[0]
      x[1, :, :] -= mean[1]
      x[2, :, :] -= mean[2]
      if std is not None:
        x[0, :, :] /= std[0]
        x[1, :, :] /= std[1]
        x[2, :, :] /= std[2]
    else:
      x[:, 0, :, :] -= mean[0]
      x[:, 1, :, :] -= mean[1]
      x[:, 2, :, :] -= mean[2]
      if std is not None:
        x[:, 0, :, :] /= std[0]
        x[:, 1, :, :] /= std[1]
        x[:, 2, :, :] /= std[2]
  else:
    x[..., 0] -= mean[0]
    x[..., 1] -= mean[1]
    x[..., 2] -= mean[2]
    if std is not None:
      x[..., 0] /= std[0]
      x[..., 1] /= std[1]
      x[..., 2] /= std[2]
  return x
```

The description is:

> caffe: will convert the images from RGB to BGR,
> then will zero-center each color channel with
> respect to the ImageNet dataset,
> without scaling.